# Dynamically create components from a single template angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I was wondering if there's a way in angular, where one can generate components at run time, from a general template?

For example, if I have a dashboard of widgets, where a backend server tells me how many widgets are rendered, is there a way to create a component for each of the widgets and add them as child to the parent dashboard component?

This might not even be the best way to do this, but for curiosity's sake I was wondering if it was possible, and if it is, whether it is a good practice.

I've looked at dynamic components in angular, but there you've a predefined component (like a modal) which you can load/unload at runtime.

Edit: I could use ngFor/ngIf constructs if I need to display the widgets, the reason I'd want components is that I'd like to do a bunch of other tasks, like setup observables based on which widget it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the easiest solution would be to have some fixed widgets and just render them using data from your backend and `*ngFor` and `*ngIf` even tho that's not exactly a beautiful solution.

```
<div class='dashboard'>
    <ng-content *ngFor='let widget of widgets'>
        <ng-content *ngIf='widget.type == 1'><app-widget1></app-widget1></ng-content>
        ....
    </ng-content>
</div>
```

There's also the [ComponentFactoryResolver](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactoryResolver) which can be used to load components dynamicaly at runtime as described [here](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader). Haven't tried myself so I can not provide an example but there is example code on the guide and maybe it fits your needs.

Comment: That would be a good solution if I need to just display the widgets, the reason I'd want components is that I'd like to do a bunch of other tasks, like setup observables based on which widget it is. I should probably update my question to reflect this.

Comment: And I've worked with ComponentFactoryResolver, but it only allows to load/unload predefined components.

Comment: So you actually want to 'create' a component in backend with specific tasks and methods and deliver that to the frontend? Don't think that would be possible, what you could try is to deliver a JS script/file and execute that to do the task you want on your dashboard but no idea if you can connect that to your angular services or what else...

Comment: Yep. Just a thought experiment. I realize this wouldn't really be a good idea to implement in a real project.